# Display profile content row wise

Tags: mysql

i have 2 table one is field_id and other is field_value.
i want to display profile content in row wise, first name, last name, age,hobby,about me.

```
field_id
-------------------------------------------------
   id   |           name           |
--------|--------------------------|-----------------
1                   First name
2                   Last name
3                   Age
4                   Hobby
5                   About me
----------------------------------------------------------
```

field_value --here id pmkey auto increment and field_id is mentioned in up table

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
id | user_id  | field_id |   field_value                       |
---|----------|----------|--------------------------------------|----
1  | 1        |     1    |John       
2  | 1        |     1    |smith
3  | 1        |     2    |Capili
4  | 1        |     3    |32
5  | 1        |     4    |Reading Book
6  | 1        |     4    |Swimming
7  | 1        |     4    |Boating
8  | 1        |     5    |I
9  | 1        |     5    |am
10 | 1        |     5    |very
11 | 1        |     5    |simple
11 | 1        |     5    |person
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to display profile everry content in row wise like this

```
name -:john smith capili
Age-:32
Hobby-:Reading Book,Swimming,Boating
About me-:I am very simple person.
```

Please help me. and suggest me this type database we should use or not.

Comment: use select statement ... http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Comment: Where do you want to display this content? in php file?

Comment: how can a person have two first name?? John and Smith as first names??

Isn't ***I am very simple person*** is one string? Why 5 rows for that?? What if some right 1000 words in About Me?? Are you going to create 1000 rows for that?? Your DB structure is WORST. Please if you are at start, change DB structure right now.

Comment: @AurA : How select only will help OP?

Comment: @FahimParkar you have edited the question now... Now it is quite clear... earlier it was a mess I would say. Now, according to this scenario I guess multiple select will be required

Comment: example :- name - Select field_value from table2 where field_id=1

I agree with you that the database structure is extremely bad.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please let me know if you have any questions...

Comment: @AurA : I have added link now. OP will need JOINS as well.

Answer (score 3):

At the least what you can get is as below.

```
John smith
Capili
32
Boating Swimming Reading Book
I am very simple person
```

To get above output use below query.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_value SEPARATOR ' ') as Profile FROM myTable
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY field_id
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddab6/7).

### ***However***, I would suggest you to change your DB Structure and make it as below.

Table **personal_details**, with following fields.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ field     +  type   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ personID  + INT     +
+ firstName + varchar +
+ middleName+ varchar +
+ lastName  + varchar +
+ age       + INT     +
+ aboutMe   + varchar +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**hobbies_person** table

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ field     +  type   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ personID  + INT     +
+ hobbID    + INT     +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**hobbies** table

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ field     +  type   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ hobbID    + INT     +
+ hobbName  + varchar +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I have added new table as **hobbies** because if we don't have **hobbies** table then for each person we have to write hobbies name (extra field too & increase in size too). In **hobbies_person** we will already have hobbies defined and person write new hobby then it would be first added into **hobbies** table and then **hobbies_person** table.

### See, [New Database Structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78553/3) for more details.

Comment: Much better database structure, I guess this should help him.

Comment: thanks for suggest me. Sir one question if we join 40 to 60 tables then can it slow mysql fetching data,

Comment: yes, if there are more JOIN fetching is slower. At that time you will have too use JOINS that is needed i.e. right join, left join, etc...